# how to do big-O analysis when 2 algorithms are involved

Tags: big-o

I'm confused about how to do big-O analysis for the following problem -

find an element from an array of integers. ( an example problem)

my solution

1. sort the array using bubble sort ( n^2 )
2. binary search on the array for a given element (logn)

now the big-O for this is n^2 or n^2 + logn ? Should we only consider the higher term ?

Comment: You do realize there is a more efficient way to solve that example problem, right?

Answer (score 3):

Big-O for a *problem* is that of the *best* algorithm that exists for a problem.  That for an *algorithm* made of two steps (like yours) is indeed the highest of the two, because e.g.

```
O(n^2) == O(n^2 + log n)
```

However, you can't say that `O(n^2)` is the correct `O` for your sample *problem* without proving that no better algorithm exists (which is of course not the case in the example;-).

Comment: if i plot a graph with T as time and N as input, then would the
graph be N^2 or something else ? In other words will empirical analysis agree with theoretical ?

Comment: @nd81, the graph will be "indistinguishable from" (a noisy version of;-) `K * N^2` for some constant `K` (which depends on the _implementation_ of the algorithm, including the HW, &c) _for sufficiently high values of N_ (and orderings of the input chosen to give the worst result, since big-O means _worst case_, **not** average) -- in practice, bubblesort has `N^2` average, too, not just worst-case -- so, if you do several samples at each input size, and average the times, you'll get that shape of graph (noisy in inverse proportion to how many samples per input size you take) for **big** N.

Comment: Strictly speaking, if algorithm A has complexity O(n^2), and algorithm B has complexity O(n log n), it is still correct to say
that algorithm B is O(n^2).  Big-O notation represents an upper bound, not necessarily a tight bound.

Comment: @Jim, strictly speaking you're right (e.g. in a graduate degree in CS), but in the real world somebody saying mergesort is `O(N squared)` will get the same kind of reaction as somebody saying "I never murder coworkers on Tuesdays" -- which is true in exactly the same way if you never murder coworkers at all, if you think about it!-)  (the _semantics_ of the assertion are perfect but its _pragmatics_ are out of whack, in linguistics parlance;-).

Comment: I'm sure we've both come away from this conversation O(1) wiser than before.

Answer (score 1):

Only the higher order term. The complexity is always the complexity of the highest term.

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it, it would be O(n^2), since for large n, n^2 >>> logn

Comment: more specifically, for large n and any a > 0, n^a > logn

Answer (score 0):

To put the analysis, well, more-practically (if you prefer, crudely) than Alex did, the added **log n** doesn't have an appreciable effect on the outcome. Consider analyzing this in a real-world system with one million inputs, each of which takes one millisecond to sort, and one millisecond to search (it's a highly-hypothetical example). Given O(n^2), the sort takes over thirty years. The search takes an additional 0.014 seconds. Which part do you care about improving? :)

Now, you'll see algorithms which clock in at **O(n^2 x logn)**. The effect of multiplying **n^2** by **log n** makes **log n** significant - in our example, it sees our thirty years and raises us four centuries.